# Replace bean in Spring for test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a PaymentService in my Spring context and I want to replace it with mocked version in my test.
I I use `@Primary` with profile the bean will be replaced for all tests, and not just for that one.
Using `@ContextConfiguration` will not override provided bean, it will load only ones that are provided.

Is there a way to replace just one bean for just one test?

Comment: That is what `@MockBean` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by M Deinum @MockBean worked!

I have added following in my test and the service was properly mocked:

```java
@MockBean
PaymentService paymentService;
```

Comment: Could you convert this into a proper answer?